# How to select a substring between two ' '

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script who receives a String with this format:

```
ACTIVE            '/dev/xenlvm/backups' [20.00 GiB] inherit
```

I need the substring who is between ' ', so /dev/xenlvm/backups

I know than I could use the ##* operator and %%、but I've always used it with characters as []. How I can specify it, if my delimiters are ' ?

```
tmp=${var##*[}
echo "${tmp%%]*}"
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the `read` shell builtin. Those usually are faster that executing external command.

```
bash-4.2$ tmp="ACTIVE            '/dev/xenlvm/backups' [20.00 GiB] inherit"
bash-4.2$ IFS="'" read path path blah <<< "$tmp"
bash-4.2$ echo "$path"
/dev/xenlvm/backups
```

Answer (score 2):

escape it ?

```
$ tmp="ACTIVE            '/dev/xenlvm/backups' [20.00 GiB] inherit"
$ echo $tmp
ACTIVE '/dev/xenlvm/backups' [20.00 GiB] inherit
$ tmp="${tmp#*\'}"
$ echo $tmp
/dev/xenlvm/backups' [20.00 GiB] inherit
$ tmp="${tmp%\'*}"
$ echo $tmp
/dev/xenlvm/backups
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html):

> cut - cut out selected fields of each line of a file

A single quote is natural delimiter here so something like this:

```
path=$(echo $stuff | cut -f2 -d"'")
```

This, of course, assumes that you don't have to deal with nested or escaped single quotes.

Comment: Your option is working great, So since the delimiter is ' I can't use the bash tricks.
Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @xavierds: There might be a `${}` trick that will do it but all the stuff in `/usr/bin` is part of shell scripting too so there's no reason not to use it. "It works" is usually a pretty decent starting point :)

Comment: I see, I will follow with this ;). I'm sorry but since I'm new I can't vote you positively, have a good week ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your strings vary more than the original description, then you'll need regex. I would use something like

```
echo $line_of_file | sed -n -e "/ACTIVE/ s|.*'\(.*\)'.*|\1|p"
```